# Modifying file content using python

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

I have a file that consists of a single line:

```
a,x,b,c,d,e
```

I want to convert this into

```
a,x,b,x,c,x,d,x,e,x
```

Is there any easy way to achieve this with python?

Comment: What is the pattern? an x after any letter that is not x or followed by x?

Comment: its x after any letter thats not x

Comment: By that definition your original example is wrong. Unless you meant: x after any letter that's not x, unless already followed by x. What should `a,x,x,b,x,c,d,e` give?

Comment: That pattern wont occur..The input is specific which i am parsing from an html table ..lets say a is the name of class I am taking and x is grade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 my_file = open(filename)
 data = my_file.read()
 data = data.split(',')
 str = ''
 for each in data:
     if each != 'x':
         str += each + ',' + 'x' + ','
 str= str.strip(',')
 print str
```

Comment: gives: a,x,x,x,b,x,c,x,d,x,e,x

Comment: Is there any easier way if we suppose that the file is a csv file using csv module or pandas?

Comment: if its csv file better to use csv.DictReader

Comment: Sorry i didn't check the x

Comment: @M4rtini please check now

Comment: now gives: a,x,b,x,c,x,d,x,e,x. correct by op's example. But what it there are multiple x's in a row? should they be dropped?

Comment: How do i do it with csv.DictReader?Can you post it as separate answer

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
s = open(filename).read()
open(filename, 'w').write(',x,'.join(re.findall(r'[a-wyz]', s)) + ',x\n')
```